# Vue: sort array based on object order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

Given an array like this:

```
var endArray = [34, 35, 32]
```

And an object like this:

```
var order = [{"id":35},{"id":34},{"id":32},{"id":30},{"id":28},{"id":24},{"id":17},{"id":15},{"id":3}]
```

How can I re-sort `endArray` when `order` is changed? I'm working in Vue so I can write a watcher like so:

```
watch: {
  order: function (newObject) {
    // resort endArray here somehow
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to map the order to sort `endArray`.

**Update**

Expected result is:

```
endArray = [35, 34, 32]
```

To match the order of `id` keys set in `order`.

Comment: Do you want to sort `endArray` based on order of `order` array ?

Comment: please add input and the wanted result.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: why not you create array from object  given ?

Comment: There are other factors at play beyond how I've simplified the problem for SO, i..e, the array controls the IDs selected, the object controls the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the array for getting the first three objects and map `id`.

```
watch: {
    order: function (newObject) {
        endArray = newObject.slice(0, 3).map(({ id }) => id);
    }
}
```

A different solution could be to sort the array.

```
watch: {
    order: function (newObject) {
        const getIndex = id => newObject.findIndex(o => o.id === id);
        endArray.sort((a, b) => getIndex(a) - getIndex(b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Since we have an array of primitives, I think is better to use `indexOf` method.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, the `order` array contains objects, as i see it ...

Comment: Going to have to go with this one since it's super succinct and was the first one that worked. _Thank-you._

Comment: You can even make a computed property: `endArray() { return newObject.slice(0, 3).map(({ id }) => id); }`

Answer (score 1):

Make an array to find ids and split it by length of given array/OR direct provide length if known here `3`.

```js
var endArray = [34, 35, 32];
var order = [{"id":35},{"id":34},{"id":32},{"id":30},{"id":28},{"id":24},{"id":17},{"id":15},{"id":3}];
var orderIds = order.map(function(e){return e.id});
console.log(orderIds.splice(0,endArray.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sort` method by passing a `callback` provided function. I used `indexOf` function in order to *find* the `index` of a specified `element`.

```js
var endArray = [34, 35, 32]
var order = [{"id":35},{"id":34},{"id":32},{"id":30},{"id":28},{"id":24},{"id":17},{"id":15},{"id":3}]

var orderIds = order.map(({id}) => id);
endArray.sort((a,b) => orderIds.indexOf(a) - orderIds.indexOf(b));
console.log(endArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this problem is to divide the problem in steps:

Since you want to sort the array, you want to call `endArray.sort((a, b) => {})`

On what do you want to sort? The index where the idcould be found:

```
endArray.sort((a, b) => {
    let indexA;
    for(indexA = 0; indexA < this.order.length; indexA++) {
        if (this.order[indexA].id === a) break;
    }
    let indexB;
    for(indexB = 0; indexB < this.order.length; indexB++) {
        if (this.order[indexB].id === b) break;
    }
    // ...
})
```

How do we want to sort it? ascending:

```
endArray.sort((a, b) => {
    let indexA;
    for(indexA = 0; indexA < this.order.length; indexA++) {
        if (this.order[indexA].id === a) break;
    }
    let indexB;
    for(indexB = 0; indexB < this.order.length; indexB++) {
        if (this.order[indexB].id === b) break;
    }
    if (indexA > indexB) return 1;
    if (indexB > indexA) return -1;
    return 0;
})
```

When do we want to sort it? When `order` or `newArray` changes:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        orderString: '[{"id":35},{"id":34},{"id":32},{"id":30},{"id":28},{"id":24},{"id":17},{"id":15},{"id":3}]',
        newArrayString: '[34, 35, 32]',
    },
    computed: {
        order() {
            return JSON.parse(this.orderString);
        },
        newArray() {
            return JSON.parse(this.newArrayString);
        },
        result() {
            //  Make a copy to prevent editing the original data
            return [...this.newArray].sort((a, b) => {
        let indexA;
        for(indexA = 0; indexA < this.order.length; indexA++) {
            if (this.order[indexA].id === a) break;
        }
        let indexB;
        for(indexB = 0; indexB < this.order.length; indexB++) {
            if (this.order[indexB].id === b) break;
        }
        if (indexA > indexB) return 1;
        if (indexB > indexA) return -1;
        return 0;
    })
        }
    },
})
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <p>
        Order:
        <textarea v-model="orderString"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        NewArray:
        <textarea v-model="newArrayString"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        Result:
        {{ result }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (order.indexOf(a.id) > order.indexOf(b.id))
    return -1;

  if (order.indexOf(a.id) < order.indexOf(b.id))
    return 1;

  return 0;
}

endArray.sort(compare);
```

Looks like you're looking for the sort function on an array. Basically, you create a comparer and pass the function to the sort function.

In your situation, you would include logic to check/compare the values against the order array, in the comparer.

**More info:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: where did the `last_nom` variable in your answer came from? its not inside the question.

Comment: My bad, used an example I had available in an editor.

Comment: in your new example you seem to have confused the the contents of `newArray` and `order`, `newArray` is a list of numbers, `order`is a list of objects containing a key-value pair: `id: number`